# Log not working in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-logcat, google-cloud-messaging

code for registering using asynctask :

```
import java.io.IOException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;  
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.android.gms.gcm.GoogleCloudMessaging;
public class RegisterApp extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    private static final String TAG = "GCMRelated";
    Context ctx;
    GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    String SENDER_ID = "10413";
    String regid = null; 
    private int appVersion;


    public RegisterApp(Context ctx, GoogleCloudMessaging gcm, int appVersion){
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.gcm = gcm;
        this.appVersion = appVersion;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        String msg = "";
        try{
            if (gcm == null){
                gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(ctx);
            }
            regid = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
            msg = "Device registered, registration ID=" + regid;
            Log.i(TAG,msg);

        } catch (IOException e){
            msg = "Error: " + e.getMessage();
        }

        return msg;
    }


    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        Toast.makeText(ctx, 
          "Registration Completed. Now you can see the notifications", 
          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
          .show();
          Log.v(TAG, result); 
    }
}
```

Here `toast` is working in `onPostExecute()` but Log is not working anywhere.what i am trying to show is `result` and `msg` in Logcat.

More to know is where can i define log to place in information in Logcat? Do I have to do it in main UI thread or it can be done from anywhere in android system?

Here is Logcat:
[image]

Comment: Do you see the log `Log.i(TAG,msg);` in `doInBackground(params)`

Comment: restart the ide, it will work

Comment: Use Log.e some devices does not support Log.i and Log.d I have faced a similar situation earlier

Comment: you can place Log in onProgressUpdate  method of AsyncTask Class and can check it in LogCat

Comment: its working @Sreekanth

Comment: Disconnect the device , close IDE , then start IDE and connect device , it worked for me